# how to add active class on menu in codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery

I'm adding an 'active' class to clicked menu bar items but it is removing when page goes to other link after click.

This is my HTML:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="active">
        <a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>news">News / Article</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>players">Players</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>forum">Forum</a>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>rules" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Rules <b class="caret"></b></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li>
                <a href="#">Action</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Another action</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <?php if(!empty($session)){ ?>
    <li>
        <a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>profile">Profile</a>
    </li>
    <?php } ?>
    <li>
        <a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>gallery">Gallery</a>
    </li>
    <?php if(empty($session)){ ?>
    <li>
        <a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>register">Register</a>
    </li>
    <?php } ?>
</ul>
```

Javascript:

```
$(".nav li").click(function () {
    $(".nav li").removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

Comment: is it a single page site ?

Comment: You cannot do that only that js. You need to read current url and decide which url to be active. See my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24080622/how-to-add-active-class-on-menu-in-codeigniter/24080990#24080990)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do that with only that javascript. You need to get data from url and decide which menu to be active.

First get current url in page. And do following operation;

```
$(".nav li").removeClass('active');
var urlType = document.URL.split("/");
$("a[href*='/" + urlType + "']").addClass("active"); // contains /players
```

When you go this url;

```
http://yourdomain.com/players;
```

the js will be;

```
$(".nav li").removeClass('active');
$("a[href*='players']").addClass("active");
```

And **Players** menu will be active

Answer (score 0):

The active class probably removes because you're loading a new view when you click on a link and this loads some other HTML.

Comment: i am using the common header and footer view  .  the only content data is different for different views.

Answer (score 0):

You are re-loading the site, so it load the HTML like the first time.

So you only will have the 'active' class until you don't leave or reload that website.

A way to fix it , load the content by Ajax, and the menu will not change.

I hope it will help you.